# Apple Watch: how to show image in Glance

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am trying to show an image in Glance View. The image format is .png, and I have placed it in WatchKitApp bundle.

In Glance, I have added a WKInterfaceImage in default group presented in Glance.

below is my code to dynamically locate an image to it.

```
//
//  GlanceController.swift
//  Zappatap WatchKit Extension
//
//  Created by Muhammad Umar on 4/5/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Zivato. All rights reserved.
//

import WatchKit
import Foundation


class GlanceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var glanceLable: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var glanceImage: WKInterfaceImage!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        glanceLable.setText("This is new Glance")
        glanceImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "happy@2x.png"))
        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having the same problem. The image appears in Storyboard, but not on the actual Watch.

Answer (score 1):

If your image is in the WatchApp bundle then you want to use `setImageNamed()` so it loads the image on the watch instead of loading it on the phone and sending it over bluetooth.  You also don't need to include the @2x or file extension, so it would just be:

```
glanceImage.setImageNamed("happy")
```

You should also be able to just set the image in the storyboard if it's always going to be the same.